iOS Swift - How often should you fetch `AAAttribution.attributionToken()`
In my iOS app I submit the AAAttribution.attributionToken() to the Apple Servers in order to determine whether the user has installed the app through an Apple Search Ad.
At the moment I only fetch this once; as soon as the Apple Server has responded I save the result and future app launches won't fetch this again if they find a local copy of the results.
Can the server response change/update after a while? Are there scenarios in which I should re-fetch this?
The only thing I can think of is users re-downloading the app from an ad but I can't find much documentation on this from Apple
